# Best Practices for Separating Database Security from Application Tier

Tags: oracle, security, oracle11g

In the Oracle documentation, it is repeatedly mentioned that it is preferable for all users of an application to be database users instead of just records in some kind of 'user' table for numerous reasons. For example, at docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/… -- "Where possible, you should build applications in which application users are database users. In this way, you can leverage the intrinsic security mechanisms of the database."

I am reasonably familiar with what they call the One Big Application User pattern, but I have been suitably convinced that this is not the best way. However, it seems that creating a database user for every web user is not particularly possible either, so my question is, what are some best practices for keeping the security definition of your data separate from the application that accesses it?

Some ideas:

- A secure interface in between the database and the application. Application never knows about the database.
- Create views that utilize application context to automatically filter out rows that the application user cannot read, and only grant the application user access to the view.
- Similarly create procedures that utilize application context to only allow authorized data access/manipulation.

I am currently using Oracle 11g XE, and I'd like to avoid solutions that involve additional Oracle products like their Internet Directory or Middleware.

Comment: "In the Oracle documentation"... where? It is certainly NOT true that it is preferable for all users of an application to have a database user account.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/app_devs.htm#DBSEG98114 -- "Where possible, you should build applications in which application users are database users. In this way, you can leverage the intrinsic security mechanisms of the database."

Comment: "Where possible" are important words here. In the case of a web application potentially serving 1000s of users, it's not scaleable to dynamically create each user on the database.

Comment: Perhaps, but why? Is 'CREATE USER ...' significantly more overhead than 'INSERT INTO Users ...'? My doubts were more along the lines that it would be a bad idea to let the application user be able to create new database users if it couldn't be restricted to only granting its new users application rights...

Comment: You can't insert into data dictionary views. But anyway, I would pity the dba who logs into your database to find 1000s of empty schemas all over the place.

Comment: Ah. Yes I read that users who are identified globally do not get schemas, so perhaps this is why these kinds of features are restricted to the enterprise edition, where the application would possibly create a LDAP user in some OU that can authenticate to the database and automatically get a certain role...

Its a shame, I really liked the idea of having user management and security independent from the application.

Comment: I would still have security managed separately from the app, but just not using Oracle db accounts.

Comment: I've rephrased my question based on your input.